# My custom UIView dos not receive touches

Tags: ios, uiview, nib

Using IB, I have created a small subview that contains a few buttons. My controller reads the small view from the xib-file and adds it as a subview to the main view. It loads okay, I can see the subview and all its buttons. As far as I can see, It does also connect to the IBOutlets and IBActions in the controller.

However, when I press a button nothing happens! In fact, when I press a button *the super view's touchesBegan is invoked!* 
The super view does also contain an "ordinary button" (i.e. a sibling to my subview) and that button works okay! Problem: Why does not the buttons on my subview work?

```
-(void) loadMultibutt{
    self.buttErase = nil; // test if the outlet connects
    NSArray *arr = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                    loadNibNamed:@"multibutt_ipad" owner:self options:nil];

    UIView *viewButts = [arr objectAtIndex:0];
    ViewWorkbench* vw = (ViewWorkbench*) self.view;
    [vw addMultibuttView:viewButts];

    // now, buttErase != nil.
    NSSet *setTest = [self.buttErase allTargets];
    NSLog(@"setTest = %@", setTest); // This works!
}
```

Comment: Do you have user interaction enabled -- either in the xib-file or by setting the UIView property userInteractionEnabled?

Comment: @CharliePrice Yes, user interaction is enabled in the xib-file.

Comment: Check the size of the UIView. It could be that its size is smaller than the content (subviews) inside of it, and that you are not clipping it.That allows you to see all subviews but you will not be able to interact with them. Try this  [theView setClipsToBounds:YES];  and check if you still see the subviews. If you don't then that's it. If so, just make it bigger on IBuilder.

Comment: @sEnC Thanks, I have to dig into this! All buttons becomes invisible when I invoke [theView setClipsToBounds:YES]; ! Still, the view's frame size is exactly what it should be (110x184), large enough to contain the buttons...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on  your reply I feel safe concluding that your problem is that the parent view of your buttons does not contain the buttons in its interactive area. You can still see them because you are not clipping the subviews, but still you can't interact with them. There are two options to solve your problem

a) (Recommended)Place the buttons in the proper place so that they are within the visible (and interactive area of the parent view)

b) Override the hitTest selector of the parent view, so that it tracks all of touches in its subviews, including those outside of its bounds. For that you will have to create a subclass of UIView and implement the following:

```
-(UIView *) hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
UIView* result = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
if (result)
    return result;
for (UIView* sub in [self.subviews reverseObjectEnumerator]) {
    CGPoint pt = [self convertPoint:point toView:sub];
    result = [sub hitTest:pt withEvent:event];
    if (result)
        return result;
}
return nil;
```

}

Comment: Yes, the problem was the buttons parent view. When I set the foreground color of that view, I could only see the color in a small area, the remaining part was transparent, and only the colored part was active. I fixed the problem by deselecting every line in the autosize box in IB. Thanks!