# Can't click on UIButton (that appears programmatically) after animation gets done

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, core-animation, calayer

Just had a small question. I'm trying to make a UIButton appear programmatically, which I have to animate. But once the animation gets done, I can't click the button for some reason.

I have a CALayer "animationLayer" as a sublayer of the UIView, and within that animationLayer, I have three CAShapeLayers "pathLayers" (which I use to animate three different path ways as you can see in the diagram below). And within those pathLayers, I'm adding three buttons as their respective sublayers so that I can have an animation where the buttons move along the path as the path draws itself. Everything was working good until I tried adding a button as a sublayer of the pathLayer. Now when I click on the button, it's supposed to go to a method that logs on the console window "Button has been pressed". I've tried setting the self.view.userInteractionenabled to YES but that still gives me nothing.

Why I can't click it?

Here's some relevant parts of the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.animationLayer = [CALayer layer];
    self.animationLayer.frame = CGRectMake(20.0f, 64.0f, 
    CGRectGetWidth(self.view.layer.bounds) - 40.0f, CGRectGetHeight(self.view.layer.bounds) - 84.0f);

    [self.view.layer addSublayer:self.animationLayer];
}

- (id)createUIButtonwithXPosition:(CGFloat)x YPosition:(CGFloat)y Width:(CGFloat)width Height:(CGFloat)height
{
    UIImage *lionImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"noun_project_347_2.png"];
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(logger:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
    button.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
//    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [button setBackgroundImage:lionImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:button];

    return button;
}


- (void)setupDrawingLayer
{
    if(self.pathLayer != nil){
        [self.pathLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
        [self.secondPathLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
        [self.thirdPathLayer removeFromSuperlayer];

        self.pathLayer = nil;
        self.secondPathLayer = nil;
        self.thirdPathLayer = nil;

        ...//Other code not relevant
}

    CGRect pathRect = CGRectInset(self.animationLayer.bounds, 100.0f, 100.0f);
    CGPoint bottomCenter = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(pathRect), (self.lionBtnVerticalAlignment.constant + self.lionBtnHeight.constant + 25.0f));
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(pathRect), CGRectGetMidY(pathRect));
    CGPoint leftCenter = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(pathRect), CGRectGetMidY(pathRect));
    CGPoint rightCenter = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(pathRect), CGRectGetMidY(pathRect));


    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

    UIBezierPath *secondPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

    UIBezierPath *thirdPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];


    [path moveToPoint:bottomCenter];
    [path addLineToPoint:center];

    [secondPath moveToPoint:bottomCenter];
    [secondPath addLineToPoint:leftCenter];

    [thirdPath moveToPoint:bottomCenter];
    [thirdPath addLineToPoint:rightCenter];

    CAShapeLayer *pathLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    pathLayer.frame = self.animationLayer.bounds;
    pathLayer.bounds = pathRect;
    pathLayer.geometryFlipped = YES;
    pathLayer.path = path.CGPath;
    pathLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    pathLayer.fillColor = nil;
    pathLayer.lineWidth = 3.0f;
    pathLayer.lineDashPattern = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:6],
                                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:2],
                                 nil];
    pathLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinBevel;


    CAShapeLayer *secondPathLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    secondPathLayer.frame = self.animationLayer.bounds;
    secondPathLayer.bounds = pathRect;
    secondPathLayer.geometryFlipped = YES;
    secondPathLayer.path = secondPath.CGPath;
    secondPathLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    secondPathLayer.fillColor = nil;
    secondPathLayer.lineWidth = 3.0f;
    secondPathLayer.lineDashPattern = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:6],
                                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:2],
                                 nil];
    secondPathLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinBevel;

    CAShapeLayer *thirdPathLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    thirdPathLayer.frame = self.animationLayer.bounds;
    thirdPathLayer.bounds = pathRect;
    thirdPathLayer.geometryFlipped = YES;
    thirdPathLayer.path = thirdPath.CGPath;
    thirdPathLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
    thirdPathLayer.fillColor = nil;
    thirdPathLayer.lineWidth = 3.0f;
    thirdPathLayer.lineDashPattern = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                       [NSNumber numberWithInt:6],
                                       [NSNumber numberWithInt:2],
                                       nil];
    thirdPathLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinBevel;

    [self.animationLayer addSublayer:pathLayer];
    [self.animationLayer addSublayer:secondPathLayer];
    [self.animationLayer addSublayer:thirdPathLayer];

    self.pathLayer = pathLayer;
    self.secondPathLayer = secondPathLayer;
    self.thirdPathLayer = thirdPathLayer;


    UIImage *lionImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"noun_project_347_2.png"];

    btn1 = (UIButton *)[self createUIButtonwithXPosition:0.0f YPosition:0.0f Width:lionImage.size.width Height:lionImage.size.height];
    btn1.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
    btn1.layer.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, lionImage.size.width, lionImage.size.height);

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:btn1];
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    ....//Other code not relevant

}


- (void)startAnimation
{
    [self.pathLayer removeAllAnimations];
    [self.secondPathLayer removeAllAnimations];
    [self.thirdPathLayer removeAllAnimations];

     ....//Other code not relevant

    CABasicAnimation *pathAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
    pathAnimation.duration = 3.0;
    pathAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
    pathAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];

    [self.pathLayer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"strokeEnd"];
    [self.secondPathLayer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"strokeEnd"];
    [self.thirdPathLayer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"strokeEnd"];

    CAKeyframeAnimation *lionAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation     animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    lionAnimation.duration=3.0;
    lionAnimation.path = self.pathLayer.path;
    lionAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;
    lionAnimation.delegate = self;

    [btn1.layer addAnimation:lionAnimation forKey:@"position"];

    btn1.layer.position = CGPointMake(365.0, 460.0);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that tapping at `365.0, 460.0` (whether or not the button appears to be there) doesn't work?

Comment: Yes sir, I'm pretty sure.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that you might be experiencing a typical problem in which a `UIView` is a sub child of another `UIView`, but outside of its bounds. To check whether this is the case, set the property of the parentview to `setClipsToBounds:YES` and you will most likely see the button disappear. Check this post for additional details: [My custom UIView dos not receive touches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16132080/my-custom-uiview-dos-not-receive-touches/16142801#16142801)

If this is the case you have a couple of options.

1. Place the button in a place where it is within the bounds of the parent view!!
2. Subclass the parent view and add the following code to is so that its subviews may respond to touches even when they are outside the bounds of the parent view.

   -(UIView *) hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

   UIView* result = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
   if (result)
       return result;
    for (UIView* sub in [self.subviews reverseObjectEnumerator]) {
       CGPoint pt = [self convertPoint:point toView:sub];
       result = [sub hitTest:pt withEvent:event];
       if (result)
           return result;
   }
   return nil;
   }

Comment: Hey Javier! I tried the whole setClipsToBounds:YES procedure but apparently that's not the case. The image of the button still remains. What I'm thinking about doing now is using an image to do the whole animation, and once the animation gets done, I'll remove the respective layers, and replace each with a UIButton at the same location where the layers ended their animation. Would this be a good approach or do you have something else in mind?

Answer (score -1):

Please try this:

```
[button setBackgroundImage:lionImage forState:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: Hey! I tried doing that, but it only made the Image disappear, it didn't do anything with regards to the clicking issue. Any other suggestions?

Comment: This code above work when u press right ? with the log message "Button has been pressed"

Comment: No, the problem is that I can't click the button. So, it doesn't even go to the button's action method (when pressed). I think because I have a UIButton inside a CALayer, the button is at the back of the layer so it can't be pressed (at least that's what I think). Because UIView itself can be seen as a CALayer, so what I'm trying to do shouldn't be difficult..lol, but for some reason, I can't make the Button clickable.